# I am a beginner and I am planning to develop my own app and I don't know how to work use 1 database on both mobile and web

Tags: android, web-services, web, mobile

I am thinking of developing an app and I don't know which service I should use for my data to run to. I tried on using Amazon Web Services but they don't offer any support for free users. And I am just a teenager who wants to develop my skills, I don't have any source of income at all. I am hoping some recommendations or help from here. Some ideas on what tools I should use.

My app is both web and I'll be making mobile app version of it and I am having a hard time about how would I make those two work from the same something like server. It's like, facebook website and the facebook app, it has only one source of data.

I hope anyone can help me...

Comment: if you have a web application that pulls data from database then create a web service so you can call it on a mobile device, read up on php web service. a starting point could be : https://codinginfinite.com/restful-web-services-php-example-php-mysql-source-code/

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I'll start working now. This will be helpful :) At least I now got an idea from a person who is experienced.

Comment: It's possible that Microsoft Azure has a free tier account that they would let you host a Web Application and Database on for free.  That would let you build the website and get it working.  Then, Azure should also allow you to create a web service/api that a mobile device could call to access the backend database.  It is a lot of work, but Microsoft has a bunch of tutorials on how to do all of those things.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I will try it out.